# SQL return only the next 1 row of same type after a certain row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 'Operations' called `Start`, `Finish`, `Available`, `Unavailable`. Every time I see a row where 'Operation' = Available, I want to only return the next 1 row where the operation = 'Start' (while keeping the 'Finish' row for that same ID) until the next row where 'Operation' = Available (which, when this happens, I want to again return only the next 1 row where Operation = Start).

So starting with this dataset

```
Time        ID          Operation
6:34:50 AM  2016544     Finish
6:33:09 AM  2016544     Start
6:32:12 AM  2015289     Finish
6:32:07 AM  2015268     Finish
6:31:53 AM  2015834     Finish
6:31:39 AM  2015539     Finish
6:31:14 AM  Available   Available
6:31:12 AM  Unavailable Unavailable
6:31:02 AM  2015289     Start
6:30:57 AM  2015268     Start
6:30:42 AM  2015834     Start
6:30:28 AM  2015539     Start
6:30:22 AM  Available   Available
```

I would like to get to this

```
Time        ID          Operation
6:34:50 AM  2016544     Finish
6:33:09 AM  2016544     Start
6:31:39 AM  2015539     Finish
6:31:14 AM  Available   Available
6:31:12 AM  Unavailable Unavailable
6:30:28 AM  2015539     Start
6:30:22 AM  Available   Available
```

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense to me.  But the sample data suggests that you want the first row after a change in operation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully follow the explanation.  But your sample data and results suggests that you want the first row where a sequence of operations of the same type appear:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(operation) over (order by time) as prev_operation
      from t
     ) t
where prev_operation is null or prev_operation <> operation;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your desired result I guess you want last operation from sequence of the same operations. Try:

```
select Time, ID, Operation
    from (
    select Time, ID, Operation,
           rownumber() over (partition by grp order by Time desc) rn
    from (
        select *,
               rownumber() over (order by time) -
                 rownumber() over (partition by Operation order by time) grp
        from MyTable
    ) a
) a where rn = 1
```